# Hard Coding of a variable, confusing C syntax

Tags: c, porting

I was just going through some C code, when I got stuck upon this piece of code.

```
void someFunction(Int32 someVariable)
{
    /* someVariable is hard coded to 2 */
    (void)someVariable;

    //some processing that has nothing to do with someVariable.
}
```

What does the author meant by the comment, "**someVariable is hard coded to 2**"?
What exactly is happening to `someVariable`?

Comment: The author was probably trying to optimize this function.  They happened to know that someVariable would always be 2, so they wrote the function to use that literal value instead of the variable.

Comment: What it makes `someVariable` equal to `2`? There are no constants involved? @VaughnCato

Comment: I'm guessing that someFunction is always called with a value of 2.

Comment: So if I replace the LOC with this line, `someVariable = 2`, would it make any difference? @VaughnCato

Comment: No, since someVariable isn't used.

Comment: Do you see a literal 2 in the someFunction code?

Comment: If you want to make it clearer, I would put `assert(someVariable==2);` at the top of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the code used to look like this, for example:

```
// Somewhere else in the source:
…someFunction(2)…
…
…x = 2;…
…someFunction(x)…
…
// Et cetera, the point being that whenever someFunction is called, its argument always has the value 2.

// The definition of someFunction:
void someFunction(Int32 someVariable)
{
    foo(someVariable*3);
    y = someVariable*7 - 4;
    bar(y);
    …
}
```

and the author changed it to this:

```
// The definition of someFunction:
void someFunction(Int32 someVariable)
{
    (void) someVariable;
    foo(6);
    y = 10;
    bar(y);
    …
}
```

So, what happened is:

- Everywhere that “someVariable” appeared in “someFunction”, the author replaced it with “2”.
- The author then reduced expressions, so that “someVariable*3” became “2*3” and then became “6”. This explains why you do not see “someVariable” in someFunction and why you do not see “2” in someFunction.

In other words, the code of someFunction now behaves the way the original code behaved when someVariable was 2. You describe the body of someFunction as “some processing that has nothing to do with someVariable”, but, in fact, it is processing that uses 2 for the variable of someVariable. Whatever role someVariable played in the function has been lost by the editing, but, presumably, this code behaves like the old code did, as long as someVariable was 2.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely this (casting of a function argument to `void`) is done to shut up the compiler, which otherwise would warn or error out because of the unused argument. Whether the value is "hard-coded" somewhere is irrelevant to the presented code.

Answer (score 4):

The statement

```
(void)someVariable;
```

will disable any compiler warning that the parameter `someVariable` is unused within the function.

If you look at the succeeding code you will probably find places where it could use the value of `someVariable` but is instead hard coded to assume that it is `2`.

Comment: I went through the rest of the code, but it itn't using `someVariable`  past the `(void)someVariable` LOC. Does it mean `someVariable` has been set to `2`, meaning `someVariable = 2`?

Comment: @SeanVaughn it's *assuming* that `someVariable` is `2`.

Comment: Why exactly 2? There is no mentioning of constants.

Comment: @SeanVaughn that would depend on what the code's doing, and what `someVariable` is.  For example, if it's a power then you would see `x*x` and `sqrt(x)` instead of `pow(x, 2)` and `pow(x, 0.5)`.